# How to use combined transactions in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactions

I have two classes. The first represents the master data, the second represents its detail data (they are connected via foreign keys).
As the detail record requires an existing master record, I have to save the master record first. Unfortunately errors can happen during the saving of the detail data so I should rollback the saving of the master in case of error as well.

I have the following code.

Master class:

```
 MyDataContext db=new MyDataContext();
 DetailData detail=new DetailData();
 using (var transaction= db.Database.BeginTransaction())
 {
  try
  {
   //db.Database.CommandTimeout = 10;
   db.SaveChanges();
   //saving details
   detail.SaveData(masterId);
   //on success
   transaction.Commit();
  }
  catch (Exception)
  {
   transaction.Rollback();
   throw;
  }
 }
```

Detail class:

```
MyDataContext db;
DataItem dataItem;

public DetailData()
{
 db=new MyDataContext();
 dataItem=new DataItem();
 db.DataItem.Attach(dataItem);
}

public SaveData(int id)
{
  dataItem.Master_ID=id;
  db.SaveChanges();
}
```

As it is [best practice by Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.aspx) to use DataContext on-demand, I do not want to pass the existing context into the detail data.

> In general, a DataContext instance is designed to last for one "unit
>   of work" however your application defines that term. A DataContext is
>   lightweight and is not expensive to create. A typical LINQ to SQL
>   application creates DataContext instances at method scope or as a
>   member of short-lived classes that represent a logical set of related
>   database operations.

Unfortunately I get a *Timeout exception* as the master transaction is not commited yet and I start a new `SaveChanges` on a different context object.

If I use `db.DataBase.UseTransaction` and pass the transaction of the master class, I get another exception about the transaction *belonging to another context*.

So how could I combine the saving of the master and the detail data into one working transaction?

Comment: If your entities are connected by a foreign key, and this relationship is known to EF, then why can't you just add the `Detail` to the `Master` and call `SaveChanges`? EF will do the hard work for you (it'll do the updates in the right order, and put the whole thing inside a transaction)?

Comment: You're right that the best practice is to keep the lifetime of the context as short as possible, but that means creating it, using it for *some operation* and then disposing it, where *some operation* may involve several database calls. You should **not** create a new one for every database call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I misunderstand your question, or perhaps the following pattern is not possible in your situation, but generally you can add master/detail records like so:

```
var customer = new Customer();
dbContext.Customers.Add(customer);

var order = new Order();
order.Customer = customer;

dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

This assumes that your `Customer` and `Order` tables are linked with a foreign key, and with suitable EF navigation properties (e.g. `order.Customer`).

Entity Framework will add the `Customer` and `Order` records in the correct order, and to the whole update inside a transaction, so both updates succeed, or neither.

---

**UPDATE**: If you have two contexts, each will be unaware of the changes made by the other - and if you try to add an object from one context into the other context, you'll get errors.

I suspect the timeout you're getting will be because each context is trying to execute some database operation within a transaction, and the first transaction is blocking the second. This is not a sign that you should "combine" the contexts - it's a sign that you should only have one context.

The quotation you added to your question talks about a *unit of work*. Your unit of work should logically include all the changes you're making, both to the master and detail record. That's the whole point. **You should only have one context!** :-) But, you can create a transaction *within* that context.

Comment: The separated context is given, as the Detail is reponsible for other operations, so it'll use other SaveChanges as well, which should not interfere with its master. So I should _combine_ somehow the separated contexes hence the title.

Comment: I'm getting inclined to create a single context...it requires a lots of testing. If I start a transaction and call many `SaveChanges`, they will be executed only at Commit, right?

Comment: Strictly speaking, they will be executed as soon as you call SaveChanges, but they will be isolated within your transaction, and potentially rolled back if you do not commit the transaction. This is good, because it means that you can retrieve the auto-generated IDs of new entities, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, I ended up using the same context by passing it as parameter. Now it seems I can roll back if anything goes wrong though I need some more testing. I accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, your Master class is trying to do two jobs: represent the master data record and manage its persistence. Ditto for the Detail class. Going against the principle of Separation of Concerns in this way is likely to throw up problems like this.

Use of the Repository and Unit Of Work patterns will help you separate the entities from the logic of managing transactions. See [Tom Dykstra's excellent tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) on the Repository and Unit Of Work patterns in MVC.